# AppDelegate or AppController

Tags: cocoa, model-view-controller, controller, delegates

While reading cocoa tutorials i've noticed that some of the tutorials use `AppDelegate` and some `AppController` for defining `IBActions` that open various windows that use subclasses of `NSWindowController`.

Is there some sort of rule of thumb for this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's just a class name. AppDelegate implies that the class's main duty is as NSApplication's delegate, whereas AppController seems to imply a broader range of responsibility.

Answer (score 11):

I create one class that is solely my app delegate, and instantiates my main controller (in `applicationWillFinishLaunching:`) and releases it (in `applicationWillTerminate:`). Then I have two classes with clearly-defined responsibilities: My main controller is the owner of the main window and the model, and the app delegate is nothing but the app delegate (and, as part of these duties, the owner of the main controller).

Comment: To clarify, does this mean that you put your main window in a separate nib file from MainMenu?

Comment: @Stephen: Yes; the main controller owns that nib and everything in it, which is usually one window and one or more array and object controllers.

Comment: By main controller, you mean the RootViewController... Right ?